# Need help generating all permutations in Jython

Tags: algorithm, list, loops, jython, permutation

I have a list that can have anything from 3 to 10 elements and I need to be able to print out all the permutations of these elements.

The issue that I'm having is that Jython doesn't seem to have any of the python or java ways of doing this (no perm() no yield etc) so I have to rely on using loops.

I've worked out the following works:

for 3 elements I do the following 3 times and that gives all options

```
list.pop(elements-2) /n list.append
list.pop(elements-3) /n list.append
print

list.pop(elements-2) /n list.append
list.amend
print
```

for 4 elements I do the same 3 times then I have to do

```
list.pop(elements-4) /n list.append
```

then previous loop 3 times then `pop(elements-4)`.  That is done 4 times.

For 5 elements I have to do the 4 element loop 5 times with a `pop(elements-5)` after each loop and so on but I can't conceptualize how to put this all nicely.

Any help would be great as I can't seem to bend any java/python solutions into the right shape.

Ok. After some more research and playing I have come up with the following code:

```
def findPerms():

  myList = [9,2,3,6]

  allPerms=[]
  elementCount = 0


  for i in myList:
    elementCount+= 1

  for i in range(0,elementCount):
    for j in range(1,elementCount):
      perm=[]
      for k in range(0,elementCount):
        perm.append(myList[k])
      if allPerms.count(perm) == 0:
        print perm
      allPerms.append(perm)

      h = myList[j]
      myList[j]=myList[j-1]
      myList[j-1] = h
```

It works fine for 3 elements but only gives 12 perms for 4 elements and 20 for 5 elements so for e > 3 it is out by a factor of e

Any ideas?

Comment: install jython 2.7beta and use itertools.permutations

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Guy and I'm glad to know that something has now been added that can be used in Jython but my other big hindrance is that I'm limited to the capabilities of JES version 4.3.  I've tried squishing itertools.permutations into that but to no avail.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz! By trying a heap of them I was able to find one that I was able to use as a basis to get something I could use.  Thanks again Guy and Dan!